# Struggling with the scope of variables and cant pass the city between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to comment it rather well, the issue I'm having is that userCity is undefined but I declared it at the top so I thought that this made it a global variable, am I correct? What I am trying to do is get the city from http://ip-api.com/json and then pass the city into the getJSON to open weather map. Sorry if the code is messy I am new. Codepen link: http://codepen.io/johnthorlby/pen/dOmaEr?editors=1111

Here is my html:

```
<div class="main" id="temp">
        <h1>Weather!</h1>
        <h2></h2>
        <h3></h3>
        <h4></h4>
        <p></p>
        <img src="" alt="weather icon"/>
    </div>
```

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = "43881a1bf31fb1b7225348b3f7839a9d";
  var userCity;
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(json, userCity)  {
    userCity = JSON.stringify(json.city);
    userCity = city.replace(/\"/g,"");
  });

  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + userCity + "&units=metric&appid=" + api, function(json, userCity) {
    var name = JSON.stringify(json.name + ", " + json.sys.country);
    var temp = JSON.stringify(json.main.temp);
    var icon = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].icon);
    var type = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].main);
    icon = icon.replace(/\"/g,"");
    type = type.replace(/\"/g,"");
    temp = Math.round(temp);
    //update h2 with city, country and temperature and testing to see what weather.icon is but comes back as undefined
    $("#temp h2").text("The temperature in " + name + " is " + temp + "°C ");
    //updates h3 with the type of weather & city is placeholder for testing the city variable
    $("#temp h3").text(type);
    //display image of weather type from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
    $("#temp img").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
  });
});
```

Comment: You are performing ajax requests man.  userCity will not be set until the first getJSON finishes, and only then if it is successful.  Since your second getJSON relies on userCity to be set, it should be moved into the success method of the first getJSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.getJSON is asynchronous, so the rest of the code executes before the callback from that request.  Here is one way to deal with this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = "43881a1bf31fb1b7225348b3f7839a9d";

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(json)  {
    var userCity = JSON.stringify(json.city);
    userCity = city.replace(/\"/g,"");    
    makeElementsFromCity(userCity);
  });
}

function makeElementsFromCity(userCity) {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + userCity + "&units=metric&appid=" + api, function(json) {
        var name = JSON.stringify(json.name + ", " + json.sys.country);
        var temp = JSON.stringify(json.main.temp);
        var icon = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].icon);
        var type = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].main);
        icon = icon.replace(/\"/g,"");
        type = type.replace(/\"/g,"");
        temp = Math.round(temp);
        //update h2 with city, country and temperature and testing to see what weather.icon is but comes back as undefined
        $("#temp h2").text("The temperature in " + name + " is " + temp + "°C ");
        //updates h3 with the type of weather & city is placeholder for testing the city variable
        $("#temp h3").text(type);
        //display image of weather type from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
        $("#temp img").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
      });
    });
}
```

As an aside, if that is your actual API key in your post, then regenerate it and don't share it in future.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still struggling to get this working. I implemented what you said and I am still getting userCity undefined on the console. [link](http://s.codepen.io/johnthorlby/debug/dOmaEr)
edit:Forgot to change a variable name, thank you very much for the help sir!

Answer (score -1):

You have a naming conflict, notice i changed one of the variable names in your callback 'uc'. I just tested and it now works. Try this...

```
  var userCity;
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(json, uc)  {
    userCity = JSON.stringify(json.city);
    userCity = city.replace(/\"/g,"");
  });
```

Comment: This does not address the asynchronous issue.

Comment: This alone does not solve his issue, so yes it does.  Otherwise this should be a comment, rather than an answer.